# Remove duplicates in backtracking

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `next` which essentially removes numbers from a list, in the attempt to decrease the overall size of the list.

So for example I have a list:

```
[3,2,1]
```

next will remove certain values from the list, so it'll return something like this

```
[3,2] or [3,1] or [3] or [2,1] etc
```

I'm running a script to find all possible moves:

```
findall(T, next([2,3], T), U).
```

The problem is for a list which repeats values such as:

```
L = [1,1,1,1].
```

the call

```
findall(T, next([1,1,1,1], T), U).
```

will unify `U` with `[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]`

Is there a way to make the Prolog understand that it is returning the same output multiple times?

```
next([_ | T], T).
next([H | Tin], [H | Tout]) :- 
     next(Tin, Tout).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a works for `setof/3`

```
setof(T, next([1,1,1,1], T), U)
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP say

> This does do it but it's a bit of a hacky fix, I'm looking for an alteration in the next predicate

I don't think the following it's a great solution and I suspect that it's better use `setof/3` with the original `next/2` but...

```
next(Lin, LLout) :-
  nextH(Lin, [], LLout).

nextH([], _, []).
nextH([H | Tin], Pre, LLout1) :-
  append(Pre, Tin, L),
  append(Pre, [H], Pre0),
  nextH(Tin, Pre0, LLout0),
  ( member(L, LLout0) 
    -> LLout1 = LLout0
    ;  LLout1 = [L | LLout0] ).
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

The OP ask

> how could you use setof in the next predicate?

If you use your original `next/2` predicate that generate singles lists (but I recall it `nextH`, "next helper")

```
nextH([_ | T], T).
nextH([H | Tin], [H | Tout]) :-
  nextH(Tin, Tout).
```

the `next/2` predicate that return a list of unique list become simply (using `setof/3`)

```
next(Lin, LLout) :-
  setof(Lout, nextH(Lin, Lout), LLout).
```

Comment: This does do it but it's a bit of a hacky fix, I'm looking for an alteration in the next predicate

Comment: @user3667111 - if you ask for an alteration of it, you should show us your `next/2`

Comment: @user3667111 - no, at the moment; but I don't understand the `X-3`, `X-2` part. If you want only "removes numbers from a list, in the attempt to decrease the overall size of the list", isn't enough `next([_ | T], T). next([H | Tin], [H | Tout]) :- next(Tin, Tout).` ?

Comment: Okay but for your example, write next([1,1,1] , S ) it will return  S =[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]

Comment: @user3667111 - uhmm... not exactly: from `next([1, 1, 1]), S)` I obtain three times `S` unified with `[1,1]`, not one time `S` unified with `[[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]`.

Comment: Yes exactly so you get something like X = [1, 1] ;
X = [1, 1] ;
X = [1, 1] ; right? How do you prevent this from happening? Just return the X =[1,1] once

Comment: @user3667111 - I'm reasoning on it but the ideas that I have are very similar on simulate `findall/3` and check if every solution is or isn't in the result list; that is `setof/3`. What I don't undestand why your solution use the third and the fourth clauses (the ones with `Z`).

Comment: Don't worry about them I have changed them now to your code, its much better, using findall is a hacky fix I believe

Comment: Is there a chance its not possible?

Comment: @user3667111 - improved my answer; but I don't think it's a good one.

Comment: I like your thought process, how could you use setof in the next predicate?

Comment: @user3667111 - not in the (original) `next` predicate but wrapping it in a predicate that call your original `next` predicate... give me some minute and I'll try to improve the answer.

Comment: @user3667111 - answer improved again.

Comment: Thanks man, awesome answer. I'd give you multiple thumbs up if I could

Comment: Just a question, could msort() predicate do something similar?

Comment: @user3667111 - `msort/2`? I don't think so; if I understand correctly, it doesn't remove the duplicates. Maybe `sort/2`, that is an ISO predicate and remove duplicates.